# JS: unsure why function is returning

Tags: javascript

Really novice question but why is my function returning with -1? The function does have a match so why is the function returning -1 instead of the index value. If I remove the else statement it returns with the correct out output.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let target = 5;

function search() {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === target) {
      console.log(true);
      return array.indexOf(array[i]);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

search();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the first element (index `i = 0`) against the target. If they don't match, you call `return -1`. `return` immediately exists the function. You probably want to place your return after the loop.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let target = 5;

function search() {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === target) {
      console.log(true);
      return i;
    } 
  }

  console.log(false);
  return -1;

}

search();
```

Furhtermore it's not necessary to do `array.indexOf` inside the loop, because if `array[i] == target` you already have the correct index `i`

Answer (score 1):

Because it checks the first item of the loop. It doesn't match so it returns -1. If you remove the *else*, the if matches only with the 5th item, so it returns the correct  value.

Solution:

```
function search() {
  return array.indexOf(target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**why?**

Because the loop was break on first iteration fails

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let target = 5;

function search() {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     console.log('execute',i)
    if (array[i] === target) {
      console.log(true);
      return array.indexOf(array[i]);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

search();
```

**Solution**

You need declare local variable as `-1` the run the loop. After loop finish return the local variable. Already index are iterated so just return `i` instead `array.indexOf(array[i])`

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let target = 5;

function search() {
  let res = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === target) {
      res = i
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(search());
```

**optimised**

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let target = 5;

function search() {
  return array.indexOf(target);
}

console.log(search());
```

Comment: What sense does it make, to search again for the correct index with `indexOf` if one already has the correct index `i`? What sense does it make to continue iteration, once an element is found?

Comment: yes.. i have post one by one solution from problem, solution and optimised. check now

Comment: This whole problem looks a bit like a homework exercise. I'm not sure, that just calling a built-in function will count as "optimized" solution to the problem ...

Comment: may be. But i need post better solution what i learn from stackoverflow. That was what i do :-)